# Assistance with javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone please help me with this javascript code...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  addEventListener("load", function() {
    function callback(){
        setTimeout(showIt, (parseInt(Math.random()*(60000 - 10000)) + 10000));}
  document.body.click();
  });
</script>
```

I tried to make it wait for page load, then wait for random amount of time, and finally click anywhere in the body...
How can i make this work??

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to attach the event listener to `window` for it to work. `window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){});`

Comment: @evolutionxbox — `window` is the default object in a web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onload function just defines a function called `callback`. It doesn't ever call it, so nothing inside it will happen.

Get rid of that function and put your code directly in the event handler function instead.

```js
addEventListener("load", function() {
  setTimeout(showIt, 500); //simplified timer
  document.body.click();
});


function showIt() {
  alert(1);
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

---

As an aside:

```
(parseInt(Math.random()*(60000 - 10000)) + 10000))
```

Don't use parseInt without a radix! You might have a number starting with `0` which won't be treated as a decimal.

You can simply that to:

```
setTimeout(showIt, ((Math.random() * 5) + 1) * 10000);
```

Comment: Last question, where exactly is the best place to put this code?... i'm new to JS..programming in general.. but find it very interesting so I like trying new things..

Comment: Ignoring the part where I've added code that needs to add the body element: It doesn't make a great deal of difference and people have different opinions about where the best place is.